# VBS, fso.FolderExists how to set the path correctly

Tags: vbscript

I am a new joiner :) 
I have wrote a script to rename a custom file on a client's C: drive. Script does its job finely. The only trouble is, at the end, in order to be sure the folder is renamed or not, I run fso.FolderExists script to check if there is that file exists or not. There I fail :( Script renames the file but always gives the error message. I am assuming, I am putting the patch incorrectly, therefore it can not check it. On Local machine it works fine, issue is only with Remote Machine.
Anybody would advise me, how I can check if the file renamed or not. Cheers and regards

```
strComputer = inputbox("Please enter machine name", "CustomTitle")

strComputer = Trim(strComputer)
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    boolCode = objShell.Run("Ping -n 1 -w 200 " & strComputer, 0, True)
    If boolCode = 0 Then
        Ping = True
    Else
        Ping = False
    End If

If IsNull(strComputer) Or strComputer = "" Then
        WScript.Echo "No PC name. Quitting.."
        WScript.Quit
    Elseif Ping = False Then
        WScript.Echo " " & strComputer & " is offline or inccorect name. Quitting.."
        WScript.Quit
else
WScript.Echo " " & strComputer & " is online. Click OK to continue. " & strUser
end if
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem")

For Each objItem in colItems
arrName = Split(objItem.UserName, "\")

Next
strUser = arrName(1)

If msgbox("Click YES to continue. Current logged in user: " & strUser,4096+64+4,"Confirm the user") = 
vbNo Then
WScript.Quit

End If

Set colFolders = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Directory where name = 'c:\\Users\\" & strUser &"\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\MyCustomFolder'")

For Each objFolder in colFolders
errResults = objFolder.Rename("C:\Users\" & strUser &"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OLD.MyCustomFolder")

Set colFolders = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Directory where name = 'c:\\Users\\" & strUser &"\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\MyCustomFolder'")

next

For Each objFolder in colFolders
errResults = objFolder.Rename("C:\Users\" & strUser &"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\OLD.MyCustomFolder")

Next

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FolderExists("c:\\Users\\" & strUser &"\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\OLD.MyCustomFolder") Then 

wscript.echo "Done !"

Else

wscript.echo "Oops! File couldn't be renamed"

End If
```

Comment: `FolderExists()` method of the `FileSystemObject` expects a physical file path as a string variable not a WMI query, something like `"C:\Users\" & strUser &"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\OLD.MyCustomFolder"`.

Comment: On local machine the script does its job. On Remote machine, even tho it renames the file, but it can not find the renamed file. Thus turns out - "Oops! File couldn't be renamed". Any workaround would be much appreciated.

Comment: @lankymart Thank you for your answer. I have tried that as well. But still no luck. It is fine on local machine, but still can not find the renamed file on Remote machine.